# Problemas com jquery para ler json

Tags: jquery

-- Editado--

Não estou conseguindo resolver um problema no meu código. 
Eu utilizo o jquery pra fazer uma requisição buscando um código de barras. Até consigo buscar o valor mas não consigo associar a minha função para montar a tabela. O erro é especificamente ao montar as tds onde não consigo o valor de 
text(data.produto) por exemplo.

```
 var codigo = $("#codigo_barras");
codigo.on("keydown",function(e){
      if(e.which == 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.get("controle/pedido-troca-pendente-busca-produto.php?codigo="+codigo.val(),geraLinha);
      }
});

function geraLinha(data){
  var produto = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  console.log(produto);
  var linha  = $("<tr>");
  var colunaProduto = $("<td>").text(data.produto);
  var colunaTamanho = $("<td>").text(data.tamanho);
  var colunaPreco = $("<td>").text(data.preco);
  var colunaUsuario = $("<td>").text(data.usuario);
  linha.append(colunaProduto);
  linha.append(colunaTamanho);
  linha.append(colunaPreco);
  linha.append(colunaUsuario);
  $("#troca-pendente").append(linha);
}
```

resposta no console:

```
{id_produto: "1", produto: "Tenis Azul", tamanho: "33", cod_barras: "33", tipo_cobranca: "1", …}
```

o html

```
<tbody id="troca-pendente">
</tbody>
```

Comment: Bruno, o que voce espera com essa atribuição? var linha = $("<tr>");

Comment: Criar a linha da tabela. Mas resolvi o problema. Não utilizei o objeto parseado para mostrar no text dos <td>.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o problema esta aqui, `var produto = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` você esta fazendo o parse e jogando para a variavel `produto`, mas na hora de utilizar você esta usando o `data`

```
colunaProduto = $("<td>").text(data.produto);
```

solução trocar `data.*` por `produto.*`.

```
colunaProduto = $("<td>").text(produto.produto);
```